# while http query till parentID value is '0'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm setting up a while loop to check if a parent ID exists. Every time I run this code my App crashes. First, I'm setting up a parentID from my JSON Document. After that, I run an HTTP request to an place index. in this Index, I'm getting the content (name of the city,state, land) and the next parentID for the next http request till the parentID is '0'.

in the end, I need this Output -> Europe(parentID = 0), Germany(parentID = 14), Berlin(parentID = 34).

```
   let parentID = res['_source']['parentID'];
        do {
          this.http.placeById(parentID).subscribe(analyse => {
            this.getNewParentID = analyse['_source']['parentID'];
            this.place.push(res['_source']['content']);
            parentID = this.getNewParentID;
          });
        }
        while (this.getNewParentID !== '0');
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do ... while` is an infinite loop.
The loop is synchronous and the http-call is asynchronous. So the browser ran the loop over and over, always with same `parentID`.

You should write something like this:

```
const getParent = (parentID) => {
    this.http.placeById(parentID).subscribe(analyse => {
        this.place.push(analyse['_source']['content']);
        let newParentID = analyse['_source']['parentID'];
        if (newParentID !== '0') {
            getParent(newParentID);
        }
    });
}
let firstParentID = res['_source']['parentID'];
getParent(firstParentID);
```

Comment: perfect solution